# How to calculate the number of spaces available in a music class - Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

My partner runs music classes for groups of kids and uses Google Sheets as a register. Kids sign up, stop coming, or come back all the time, so we have been hiding the rows in each sheet as and when necessary. We would now like a cell on each sheet (note: each class has it's own sheet) to show the number of spaces available which is updated each time new kid(s) are added or when a row is hidden because kid(s) have stopped attending.

I have tried using the below to show the number of spaces. 16 spaces in each class, minus the number of kids in column B.

```
=16-COUNTIF(B2:B100,"<>")
```

The problem is that this calculates the number of spaces with the hidden rows included, throwing up weird results, like minus numbers of spaces available.

How can I add on the number of hidden rows to the above formula?

Comment: Can you add link to a sample sheet that demonstrates the problem in action?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I think you might want to look into adding details of a [mcve], and for the record: please look at the descriptions of the tags you are suggested to you. **None** of the tags you selected for your question does fit your question!

Comment: I don't know if your intention is correct after the wording, but isn't it simpler to just add a `Status` column in which you can select "Attending" / "Stopped" / etc  ? You can do lots of thing based on that column. Like, number of kid currently attending, number of kid stopped coming, number of kid came back, and of course, number of space left in each class. You can always sort that column out for a list of kids that are attending the class. On the other hand, I believe that currently there is no way to know if a row is hidden or not inside a google spreadsheet, formula or script wise.

Answer (score 0):

This solution takes the suggestion by HaPhan and structures it in systematic way.

Consider the screenshot below.
1 - Green Box: there is an extra column ("Status") to record attendance information about a student.
2 - Orange Box: These are the data values for the cells in the "Status" column. All the cells in the Status Column are drop downs. This ensures consistency of spelling, categorisation, etc.
3 - Blue Box: Filters are turned on. In the "Status" column, this allows the questioner to deselect "Finished" and "Stopped" students; which would show only those students who are paid up and attending.
4 - Purple Box: These are totals for the various conditions in the "Status" column. The actual formula is described in column D.
5 - Red Box: A simple summary showing the number of seats in the class that can be sold. Assuming a maximum class size of 16 (manual data entry into cell C6) minus the number of "paid up students (a calculated value from cell C4) gives the number of available seats.

The option to filter rather than hide is significant since "selecting" and "deselecting" is extremely easy, but also automatically covers the entire column. "Hiding" and "unhiding" rows is haphazard; it can be difficult to tell whether one has found all the relevant rows.

---

[image: Screenshot]